# Blog name disappeared in Facebook share

Tags: facebook, blogger, sharing

I recently created my first blog (http://smellslikebaking.blogspot.com/) and I'm trying to customize it. I customized my share buttons and I enabled the meta tags for the posts, so that when I share on Facebook, it shows a description.

Before I did all this, when I shared on Facebook, the title of the share would be the blog name and the post name. Now, it just shows the post name and I don't know how to insert the blog name again.

Why did it disappear?

Comment: Did you install the OG tags, or are you replying on the ones in your template?

Comment: @MaryC.fromNZ I haven't installed any tags, because I didn't know what OG tags were and I don't know how to do that. Because the name showed before, I just assumed I did something and erased it by accident, but I couldn't find the fault in my code.

Answer (score 1):

OG (Open Graph) tags on a website control how Facebook "sees" it.

There must be something in either the way Blogger has done sharing icons and description meta-tags (if you used their standard features), or in the code that you used which has changed the way Facebook reads your blog.

If you want to control this, then the answer is to learn about how to install Open Graph tabs into Blogger (Google it).

Comment: I'll do that, then. Thank you so very much for your help!